# Date conversion with different gmt

Tags: php, date, gmt

I have two dates in my database

This date is from an api - `16 Nov 2017 10:54:12 +0000`

This date is from my server - `16 Nov 2017 16:24:12 +0530`

I want to convert this date into `16 Nov 2017 10:54:12 +0000` in my server time.

Comment: Read about the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateTimeZone`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) classes. They are all you need.

Comment: `$dto = new DateTime('16 Nov 2017 16:24:12 +0530');
$dto->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('UTC'));
var_dump($dto);`

Comment: I would advocate closing this question if you can. The OP isn't clear, doesn't show an attempt, and the answer doesn't explain how it would help.

Answer (score -1):

```
$value = "16 Nov 2017 10:54:12 +0000";
echo date(DATE_RFC822, strtotime($value));
```

Comment: You're code does not solve OP's problem. Try expand your thought or explain your code better